# Homomorphism theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

So I believe that I can draw a surjective homomorphism from G to A. After that I'm a little lost. Do I have to specify N as the kernel of that homomorphism or no? And if so where do I go from there?

Also this is a dumb question but is the operation in this problem multiplication? In other words when they say $|A||N|$ does that mean $|A|*|N|$?

Comment: $|A|\in\mathbb{N}$, so yes. The operation is standard multiplication.

Comment: How do you get a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $A$? Note that for *infinite* groups this isn't always possible: e.g. take $G=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $A$ is the copy of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ living inside $G$.

Answer (score 0):

The set $AN=\{xy:x\in A,y\in N\}$ is a subgroup of $G$, because $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$; moreover $N$ is obviously a normal subgroup of $AN$. The homomorphism theorem provides an isomorphism
$$
AN/N\cong A/(A\cap N)
$$
so by Lagrange's theorem,
$$
\frac{|AN|}{|N|}=\frac{|A|}{|A\cap N|}
$$

Comment: This comes from the fact that we know the size of all cosets are the same size?

Comment: @user139985 Yes, that's the reference to Lagrange's theorem: If $G$ is a finite group and $N$ a normal subgroup, then $|G/N|=|G|/|N|$.